# Test score drops below training score after a point in learning curve

Tags: python, regression, bayesian

When I plotted the learning curve for a bayesian ridge regression model, I observed that up to nearly 180 training size test score is higher than training score; but, for higher training sizes, test score is lower than training score. I have attached the learning curve below:

[image: Learning Curve]

What can be the reason of this? What might happen at that training size?

Comment: It's called "overfitting" and it happens with all models. Cut off training before the curves cross

Answer (score 0):

When you give more data to the model, it starts generalizing better. The training accuracy increases. The test accuracy is usually lower because the model is optimized for the training dataset. However, when training accuracy is very high in comparison to testing accuracy, then your model might be overfitting and you may want to regularize to reduce the high variance of the model. Overfitting is characterized by low in-sample error and high out-of-sample error.